# Is this elementary set theory proof circular?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Show $A \subset B \Rightarrow A\times C \subset B \times C$

As we have $A \subset B $

$\Rightarrow B=A \cup (B \setminus A)$

Using distributivity of the cartesian product we find:

$\Rightarrow B \times C=A \times C \cup (B \setminus A) \times C$

$\Rightarrow A \times C \subset B \times C$

QED

I am not sure if the part where $" \times C"$ is taken on both sides of the equation makes the proof circular. On the first glance I thought it was pretty elegant but I am not sure whether it does count as using the claim that we want to show.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is OK solution.

Comment: As in, "OK, not great."  If I had assigned the problem I would much rather see a direct proof such as John Watson's below.  It's a simple definition chase; no need to get fancy and invite worries about circularity.

Comment: No it is not correct because you only proved the case for simple inclusion ignoring, as you wrote, that the inclusion is proper.

Comment: Notice the difference between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$.

Comment: My personal opinion is that, if you have to ask if your proof is correct then you’re not done. The most important thing after a proof is that you should be convinced, but that doesn’t mean that you can’t ask for help. The part in your proof that you are concerned with is doing cross C on both sides. Try to prove that separately as a lemma!

Comment: @WilliamElliot there is no strict convention on the use of $\subset$. Some authors treat it as synonymous with $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do also like this:

Take any $(a,c)\in A\times C$. Then $a\in A$ and $c\in C$. But since $A\subset B$ we have also $a\in B$. So $a\in B$ and $c\in C$ and thus $(a,c)\in B\times C$. So, since $(a,c)$ is arbitrary in $A\times C$ we have $A\times C\subset B\times C$.

Comment: No.  The inclusion is proper which you did not address.

Comment: In that case, the conclusion is false when C is empty.